# using caseclass versus structtype in spark scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

When should I use Structtype, and when should I use case class.
I am trying to create a spark dataset.
I have an input CSV file, I am trying to create a dataframe first and then convert it to the dataset using df.as[].
Now in order to generate the schema, should I use structtype or case class? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use StructType when reading your CSV file **but** :

- By default all fields would be Strings unless you specify the `inferschema` option
- You'd have to name every field like this if you don't have a header

  sparkSession.read.csv("my/csv/path.csv").toDF("id","product","customer","time").as[Transaction]